# NReco PDF (Lite) and password protect

Tags: c#, pdf, nreco

Using NReco PDF Lite (which I am using in a .NET Core project), how do I secure the PDF with a password? If I cannot use Lite, which version and will it work on .NET Core?

Answer (score 2):

From NReco support:

wkhtmltopdf (which is internally used by NReco PdfGenerator) cannot produce password protected PDFs itself, but it is possible to add encryption to the produced PDF file with iTextSharp library (it is enough to use LGPL version 4.1.6 that doesn't require commercial license). This approach is illustrated in the "EncryptPdf" example (available for commercial users) and it works both for "NReco.PdfGenerator" and "NReco.PdfGenerator.LT" versions.